# How to extract keys and values from a dict and store them in an variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
db_dict={'Col1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Col2': ['2', '4', '6'], ...}
```

I want to make a string like this:

```
var simpleQuery = "col1={'1', '2', '3', '4'}&col2={'2', '4', '6'}"
```

So far I've tried this:

```
function getdbdict() {
{ %
    for key, values in dbdict.items %
}
var col = '{{key}}';
var val = '{{values}}';
var colval = col + '=' + '{' + '"' + val + '"' + '}'; { % endfor %
}
var simpleQuery = colval
```

I am a newbie, Please help me doing this.

Comment: what sort of dictionary needs arrays enclosed in `{}` ?

Comment: What do you need help with? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @ Blender: I have tried this:

Comment: `function getdbdict()
        {
            {% for key, values in dbdict.items%}
                var col = '{{key}}';
                var val = '{{values}}';
                var colval = col+'='+'{'+'"'+ val +'"'+'}';
            {% endfor %}
            var simpleQuery = colval`

Comment: You've tagged the question "javascript" but what is the `{ %` stuff? And by the way, please don't post your code in comments like that. I've copied that into your question for you, but in future note that you can amend your question by clicking "edit".

Comment: if you want to just send it to the server as a query string you can use $.param method

Comment: @claustrofob - You can use `$.param` as long as you remember to include whatever library that comes from (presumably you're talkin' jQuery).

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right, didnt noticed that it is a pure javascript

Comment: @ nnnnnn: `{% xyz %}`its Django template code style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
var db_dict={'Col1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Col2': ['2', '4', '6']};

var workingArray = []
for (var key in db_dict) {
    if (db_dict[key].length > 0)
        workingArray.push(key.toLowerCase() + "={'" + db_dict[key].join("','") + "'}");
    else
        workingArray.push(key.toLowerCase() + "={}");
}

var simpleQuery = workingArray.join("&");

console.log(simpleQuery);  // col1={'1','2','3','4'}&col2={'2','4','6'}
```

Your sample took the original object's key names and made them lowercase in `simpleQuery`, so I've done the same; obviously you can just remove the `.toLowerCase()` if that isn't needed.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rZHF/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
db_dict={'Col1': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'Col2': ['2', '4', '6']};
var str = "";
for(var key in db_dict){
  str +=key +"={";
  for(var i=0;i<db_dict[key].length; i++){
    str += db_dict[key][i];
    if(i != db_dict[key].length-1)
      str +=",";
  }
  str+="}";
  str+="&";
}
str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsbin.com/izelog/1/edit)

I am sure it can be refactored but it is just to give you an idea.